# Java Selenium How to "save image as" and press Enter

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to achieve the following :
I have the following url : https://img.pokemondb.net/sprites/sword-shield/icon/bulbasaur.png
I need to press ctrl + s via Selenium to open the download Windows window and then press enter in order to save the image.

This is my code :

```
 WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
    driver = new ChromeDriver();

    Robot robot = new Robot();

    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    
    String url = "https://img.pokemondb.net/sprites/sword-shield/icon/bulbasaur.png";
    driver.get(url);

    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_S);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_S);
    robot.delay(1000);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

When I execute this , it works everything EXCEPT the PRESS ENTER , the test open the save as window but remain there , without any exception , it just cannot press ENTER key .

Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

### Keys.ARROW_DOWN within *Context Menu*

*Context Menu* initiated through [`context_click()`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.html#selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.ActionChains.context_click) is generally invoked on a [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139) e.g. a *link*.

[`@barancev`](https://github.com/barancev) [Member of Selenium] in his [comment](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/6779#issuecomment-482789702) clearly mentions:

> **contextClick on a link opens a native context menu that can't be managed by Selenium (by design).**

---

### Conclusion

Using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) you won't be able to interact with browser native context menu items using `send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)`, `send_keys(Keys.DOWN)`, etc.